# Count the Bytes!

Tags: code-golf, internet, stack-exchange-api

### Challenge

Write a program which takes the URL of a PPCG answer as input and outputs the length of the answer's first code block in bytes.

### Code Blocks

There are three different ways of formatting code blocks:

**Four spaces before the code (`-` represents a space, here)**

```
----Code goes here
```

**Surrounding the code in `<pre>` tags:**

```html
<pre>Code goes here</pre>
```

or:

```html
<pre>
Code goes here
</pre>
```

**Surrounding the code in `<pre><code>` tags (in that order):**

```html
<pre><code>Code goes here</code></pre>
```

### Rules

You should only use the first code block in answer. Assume that the supplied answer will always have a code block.

You must find the length of the answer in *bytes*, not any other metric such as characters.

Solutions using the Stack Exchange Data Explorer or the Stack Exchange API are allowed. URL shorteners are disallowed.

Assume all programs use UTF-8 encoding.

### Examples

```
Input:  https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91904/30525
Output: 34
```

[**Link**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91904/30525)

---

```
Input:  https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91693/30525
Output: 195
```

[**Link**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91693/30525)

---

```
Input:  https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80691/30525
Output: 61
```

[**Link**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80691/30525)

*Note:* Despite what the answer may say, due to APL using a different encoding, 33 bytes [isn't its UTF-8 byte count](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#%28%E2%8C%BD%2C%7B1%2B%E2%8A%83%E2%8D%B5%7D%29%E2%88%98%7B%E2%8D%B5%2C%E2%8D%A83%C3%B7%E2%8D%A82%C3%97%E2%8A%83%E2%8D%B5%7D%283%C3%B7%E2%8D%A84%E2%88%98%C3%97%29%2C%E2%8A%A2)

### Winning

The shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: So no scraping the header?

Comment: @muddyfish Nope (note the third example)

Comment: Some languages use a custom character encoding, different than UTF-8 (I'm pretty sure that's what happens in the APL answer). So the byte count depends on each language's default encoding. I think it may be better for the challenge to ask for _character_ count rather than _byte_ count

Comment: @LuisMendo I see, I'll specify UTF-8 then

Comment: For example 2 I can only find 195 bytes. It looks like the 199 to 196 edit actually removed 4 bytes, not 3. Am I missing something?

Comment: Identation is meaningful in `<pre>` tags, and so are newlines in `<code>` tags, so your **Code goes here** examples have three different lengths. If that's intentional, it should be mentioned.

Comment: @Dennis I've now removed the indentation

Comment: But not the newlines. Both newlines in `<pre><code>\nCode goes here\n</code></pre>` count. However, they don't count in `<pre>\nCode goes here\n</pre>`

Comment: @Dennis Oh, I didn't know that :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## jQuery JavaScript, 97 Bytes

```
console.log((new Blob([$("#answer-"+location.hash.substr(1)+" code").eq(0).text().trim()])).size)
```

old version 151 Bytes

```
s=$('#answer-'+location.hash.substr(1)+' code').eq(0).text().trim();c=0;for(i=s.length;i--;)d=s.charCodeAt(i),c=d<128?c+1:d<2048?c+2:c+3;console.log(c)
```

old version 163 Bytes

```
s=$('#answer-'+location.hash.substr(1)+' code').first().text().trim();c=0;for(i=0;i<s.length;i++){d=s.charCodeAt(i);c=(d<128)?c+1:(d<2048)?c+2:c+3;}console.log(c);
```

input ist location and jQuery is active on the site

Comment: Move the `c=0` into the for, to save a byte. `for(c=i=0;i<s.lengh;i++)`

Comment: And remove the `;` before and after the `console.log(c)`.

Comment: @PaulSchmitz Thank You. I prefer to use a while loop instead of your proposal.

Comment: `s=$("#answer-"+location.hash.substr(1)+" code").eq(0).text().trim();c=0;for(i=s.length;i--;)d=s.charCodeAt(i),c=128>d?c+1:2048>d?c+2:c+3;console.log(c)` is 5 bytes shorter. 4 for removing `()` around the conditions, and 1 by replacing `while` with `for`.

Answer (score 4):

## C#, <s>249</s> 270 bytes

```
u=>{var c=new System.Net.Http.HttpClient().GetStringAsync(u).Result;var i=c.IndexOf("de>",c.IndexOf('"'+u.Split('/')[4]))+3;return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(c.Substring(i,c.IndexOf("<",i)-i-1).Replace("&gt;",">").Replace("&lt;","<").Replace("&amp;","&"));};
```

I've made some assumptions based on observations of the HTML of pages. Hopefully they hold true for all answer posts.

*+21 bytes to unencode `&amp;` to `&`. My answer failed to count it's own bytes. ;P*

Ungolfed:

```
/*Func<string, int> Lambda =*/ u => 
{
    // Download HTML of the page.
    // Although new System.New.WebClient().DownloadString(u) looks shorter, it doesn't 
    // preserve the UTF8 encoding.
    var c = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient().GetStringAsync(u).Result;

    // Using the answer id from the URL, find the index of the start of the code block.
    // Empirical observation has found that all code blocks are in <code> tags,
    // there are no other HTML tags that end with "de>",
    // and that '>' and '<' are encoded to '&gt;'/'&lt;' so no jerk can put "de>" 
    // before the first code block.
    var i = c.IndexOf("de>", c.IndexOf('"' + u.Split('/')[4])) + 3;

    // Get the substring of the code block text, unencode '>'/'<'/'&' and get the byte count.
    // Again, empirical observation shows the closing </code> tag is always on a new
    // line, so always remove 1 character when getting the substring.
    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(c.Substring(i, c.IndexOf("<", i) - i - 1).Replace("&gt;", ">").Replace("&lt;", "<")..Replace("&amp;", "&"));
};
```

Results:

```
Input:  http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91904/30525
Output: 34

Input:  http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91693/30525
Output: 195 (at the time of this answer the first post has 196, but I can't find the 196th 
byte, even counting by hand, so assuming 195 is correct)

Input:  http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80691/30525
Output: 61

Input:  http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91995/58106 (this answer)
Output: 270
```

Comment: I find 195 Bytes too

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question and my answer with 195 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7, <s>314</s> 313 bytes

```
int c(String u)throws Exception{String x="utf8",s=new java.util.Scanner(new java.net.URL(u).openStream(),x).useDelimiter("\\A").next();int j=s.indexOf("de>",s.indexOf('"'+u.split("/")[4]))+3;return s.substring(j,s.indexOf("<",j)-1).replace("&gt;",">").replace("&lt;","<").replace("&amp;","&").getBytes(x).length;}
```

Shamelessly stolen from [*@milk*'s C# answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91995/52210) and ported to Java 7.
NOTE: This assumes all code is in `<code>` blocks. Currently it won't work with just `<pre>` tags (but who uses those anyway?.. ;p).

**Ungolfed & test cases:**

```
class M{
  static int c(String u) throws Exception{
    String x = "utf8",
           s = new java.util.Scanner(new java.net.URL(u).openStream(), x).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    int j = s.indexOf("de>", s.indexOf('"'+u.split("/")[4])) + 3;
    return s.substring(j, s.indexOf("<", j) - 1).replace("&gt;", ">").replace("&lt;", "<").replace("&amp;", "&")
        .getBytes(x).length;
  }

  public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception{
    System.out.println(c("https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91904/30525"));
    System.out.println(c("https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91693/30525"));
    System.out.println(c("https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80691/30525"));
    System.out.println(c("https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91995/58106"));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
34
195
61
270
```